# How to test a javascript redirect with RSpec?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, response

I am using a xhr :post to interact with a controller, and I am expecting a redirect.
In the js.erb i have window.location.href = address .
Testing it manually, the browser gets redirected properly.
How can i test it using RSpec? response.should redirect_to fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this particular problem inspecting the response body generated by the js.erb

```
response.body.should include("window.location.href")
```

Because it didn't feel right, I will accept my own asnwer as long as it gets upvoted.

Comment: Your code works, but I think that there is a better solution to accomplish that. I opened a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581502/trouble-on-testing-a-javascript-redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with RSpec -- it does not execute Javascript. You'll need another testing tool -- some good suggestions in [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/1658763359/thoughtbot-and-the-holy-grail).