# Trouble on testing a JavaScript redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the rspec-rails 2 gem. I would like to test a JavaScript redirection but I am some trouble on doing that.

In my controller file I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{users_url}');" }
end
```

In my spec file I have:

```
it "should redirect" do
  xhr :post, :create
  response.should redirect_to(users_url)
end
```

If I run the spec I get the following:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(users_url)
   Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
```

**How can I implement the spec code so to correctly test the JavaScript redirection?**

---

**ATTEMPTS AT SOLUTION**

If I use

```
response.should render_template("window.location.replace('#{users_url}');")
```

I get

```
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template("window.location.replace('#{users_url}');")
   expecting <"window.location.replace('http://<my_application_url>/users');"> but rendering with <"">
```

If I use

```
response.should render_template(:js => "window.location.replace('#{users_url}');")
```

the spec successfully passes, but too much! That is, I can state also the following and the spec will (unexpectedly) pass:

```
response.should render_template(:js => "every_thing")
```

I have also seen [this question\answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144758/how-to-test-a-javascript-redirect-with-rspec) and the proposed solution works, but I think that is the best solution to accomplish what I aim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec controller specs use the rack_test driver, which does not execute Javascript. To test pages that use Javascript for redirection, you should really look at another driver.

[Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) with selenium-webdriver does this nicely. RSpec request specs replace your controller specs for those tests that rely on Javascript.